# Does the LSL instruction ever set the oVerflow flag in an ARM processor?

Tags: assembly, arm

If `LSL` was applied to the sign and magnitude number `0111111...`, the msb of the magnitude would become the sign bit. An overflow has occurred.

I understand that in this case, you can detect the overflow by seeing that the carry bit (set to the old msb) is not equal to the sign bit. However, I am unclear if an ARM processor would also set the oVerflow flag automatically, or if that comparison would need to be done explicitly?

Comment: When in doubt, try it. Probably faster and more reliable than asking about it on the internet :) As far as I can tell, `LSLS` is turned into `MOVS` by the assembler and the manual for that says _"Does not affect the V flag."_

Comment: for thumb there is an instruction encoding for ARM it does appear to be a pseudo instruction for mov.  but the answer to this question is clearly documented in arms documentation, not vague in any way.

Comment: other than a shift of one bit, lsl is not addition so is there a notion of signed overflow?  For use instead of multiply, again will let you read the arm documentation it is not vague in anyway, very clearly states what happens to each flag for each instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check e.g. The instruction set quick reference card at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/index.html

It shows the flags affected by each instruction. The v flag is not listed for lsl.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you want to shift by 1 in a way that will set `V`, use **`adds r1, r0,r0`**.

x+x = x*2 = x<<1 so the integer register result is the same, but `adds` does set V.